# return is not ending the for-in loop while looping through object keys JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, object, return

I am trying to make a weather app using react js. And I want to render a specific component on the basis of the weather condition value from API. The API returns the value in string format and can have space-separated words( e.g Shower Rain ). I have stored the components in a nested object.

```
const WeatherConditions = {
    Clear: {"day" : <ClearSkyDay />, "night": <ClearSkyNight />},
    Clouds: {
        "few clouds": {"day": <FewCloudsDay />, "night": <FewCloudsNight />},
        "scattered clouds": {"day": <Cloudy />, "night": <Cloudy />},
        "broken clouds": {"day": <BrokenCloudy />, "night": <BrokenCloudy />},
        "overcast clouds": {"day": <BrokenCloudy />, "night": <BrokenCloudy />}
    },
    Thunderstorm: <Thunder />,
    Drizzle : <VeryHeavyShowerRain />,
    Rain : {
        "light rain": {"day": <LightRainDay />, "night": <LightRainNight />},
        "moderate rain": {"day": <ModerateRainDay />, "night": <ModerateRainNight />},
        "heavy intensity rain": {"day": <HeavyIntensityRainDay />,"night": <HeavyIntensityRainNight />},
        "very heavy rain": {"day": <VeryHeavyRain />,"night": <VeryHeavyRain />},
        "extreme rain": {"day": <VeryHeavyRain />,"night": <VeryHeavyRain />},
        "freezing rain": {"day": <FreezingRain />,"night": <FreezingRain />},
        "light intensity shower rain": {"day": <VeryHeavyShowerRain />,"night": <VeryHeavyShowerRain />},
        "shower rain": {"day": <VeryHeavyShowerRain />,"night": <VeryHeavyShowerRain />},
        "heavy intensity shower rain": {"day": <VeryHeavyShowerRain /> ,"night": <VeryHeavyShowerRain />},
        "ragged shower rain": {"day": <VeryHeavyShowerRain />,"night": <VeryHeavyShowerRain />},
    },
    Snow: {
        "light snow": <LightSnow />, "Snow": <LightSnow />,
        "Heavy snow": <HeavySnow />, "Sleet": <HeavySnow />,
        "Light shower sleet": <HeavyShowerSnow />, "Shower sleet": <HeavyShowerSnow />,
        "Light rain and snow": <FreezingRain />, "Rain and snow": <FreezingRain />,
        "Light shower snow": <HeavyShowerSnow />,"Shower snow": <HeavyShowerSnow />, 
        "Heavy shower snow": <HeavyShowerSnow />
    },
    Mist: <Haze />, Smoke: <Haze />, Haze: <Haze />,
    Dust: <Haze />, Fog: <Haze />, Sand: <Haze />,
    Ash: <Haze />, Squall: <Haze />, Tornado: <Haze />
}
```

I am using a recursive function to get the value

```
const getCurrentWeather = (obj) => {
    for (const key in obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        if (key === weather.weather[0].main) {
            console.log(obj);
            if (typeof obj[key][Object.keys(obj[key])[0]] !== 'symbol') {
                console.log(obj);
                getCurrentWeather(obj[key]);
            }else {
                console.log(obj);
                return obj[key];
            }
        } else if (key === weather.weather[0].description) {
            console.log(obj);
            if (typeof obj[key][Object.keys(obj[key])[0]] !== 'symbol') {
                console.log(obj);
                getCurrentWeather(obj[key]);
            }else {
                console.log(obj);
                return obj[key];
            }
        } else if (key === 'day' || key === 'night') {
            console.log(obj);
            if (weather?.weather[0].icon?.includes("d")) {
                console.log(obj);
                return obj["day"];
            } else {
                console.log(obj);
                return obj["night"];
            }
        } else {
            console.log(obj);
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why the return statement is not ending thee loop. All the conditions are correct. And according to the object this should return the value and end the function but even if going through return statement it just keeps on going through all keys of the object.

```
WeatherData.js:80 {Clear: {…}, Clouds: {…}, Thunderstorm: {…}, Drizzle: {…}, Rain: {…}, …}
WeatherData.js:109 {Clear: {…}, Clouds: {…}, Thunderstorm: {…}, Drizzle: {…}, Rain: {…}, …}
WeatherData.js:80 {Clear: {…}, Clouds: {…}, Thunderstorm: {…}, Drizzle: {…}, Rain: {…}, …}
WeatherData.js:82 {Clear: {…}, Clouds: {…}, Thunderstorm: {…}, Drizzle: {…}, Rain: {…}, …}
WeatherData.js:84 {Clear: {…}, Clouds: {…}, Thunderstorm: {…}, Drizzle: {…}, Rain: {…}, …}
WeatherData.js:80 {few clouds: {…}, scattered clouds: {…}, broken clouds: {…}, overcast 
clouds: {…}}
WeatherData.js:109 {few clouds: {…}, scattered clouds: {…}, broken clouds: {…}, overcast 
clouds: {…}}
WeatherData.js:80 {few clouds: {…}, scattered clouds: {…}, broken clouds: {…}, overcast 
clouds: {…}}
WeatherData.js:109 {few clouds: {…}, scattered clouds: {…}, broken clouds: {…}, overcast 
clouds: {…}}
WeatherData.js:80 {few clouds: {…}, scattered clouds: {…}, broken clouds: {…}, overcast 
clouds: {…}}
WeatherData.js:109 {few clouds: {…}, scattered clouds: {…}, broken clouds: {…}, overcast 
clouds: {…}}
WeatherData.js:80 {few clouds: {…}, scattered clouds: {…}, broken clouds: {…}, overcast 
clouds: {…}}
WeatherData.js:91 {few clouds: {…}, scattered clouds: {…}, broken clouds: {…}, overcast 
clouds: {…}}
WeatherData.js:93 {few clouds: {…}, scattered clouds: {…}, broken clouds: {…}, overcast 
clouds: {…}}
WeatherData.js:80 {day: {…}, night: {…}}
WeatherData.js:100 {day: {…}, night: {…}}
WeatherData.js:102 {day: {…}, night: {…}}
WeatherData.js:80 {Clear: {…}, Clouds: {…}, Thunderstorm: {…}, Drizzle: {…}, Rain: {…}, …}
WeatherData.js:109 {Clear: {…}, Clouds: {…}, Thunderstorm: {…}, Drizzle: {…}, Rain: {…}, …}
WeatherData.js:80 {Clear: {…}, Clouds: {…}, Thunderstorm: {…}, Drizzle: {…}, Rain: {…}, …}
WeatherData.js:109 {Clear: {…}, Clouds: {…}, Thunderstorm: {…}, Drizzle: {…}, Rain: {…}, …}
WeatherData.js:80 {Clear: {…}, Clouds: {…}, Thunderstorm: {…}, Drizzle: {…}, Rain: {…}, …}
WeatherData.js:109 {Clear: {…}, Clouds: {…}, Thunderstorm: {…}, Drizzle: {…}, Rain: {…}, …}


....keeps going 

then it returns undefined
```

It should have stopped on line WeatherData.js:102 where it should return the value of obj["day"]. I know this is not the best practice and its Spaghetti code but I tried with less code and more recursion but no luck!

Comment: so `if (weather?.weather[0].icon?.includes("d")) {` is line 101? is it possible the `getCurrentWeather` is being called more than once? put a console.log as the first line of the funciton to check

Comment: Yes it's line 101. and no, it's being called only once from outside other than that it's being called thrice because of recursion and API value. @Bravo

Comment: you probably doing something wrong - see this a lot with reactjs, people think a function is called once, but it isn't - did you put that console.log in as I suggested to **confirm** the function is called once only? because javascript `return` never fails, ever

Comment: Yes, I put the console.log and saw the console. it's being called only once from outside. And To confirm that I am getting weather value from API I am calling this function from inside conditional useEffect with an if statement inside to check if the weather is there yet or not.

Comment: well, I can't tell you how `return` isn't performing its function - perhaps you're misidentifying the console.log output

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my issue. I initialized the local variable outside of the recursive function and then instead of returning the obj I just assigned it to the local variable and returned it outside of my for-of loop. While searching for an answer I ran into this post that says forEach/for-in loop doesn't care about returning a value they're just for iteration. So I tried with for-of loop plus this method and it worked.

```
let weatherCon = ''

const getCurrentWeather = (obj) => {
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        if (key === weather.weather[0].main) {
            if (typeof obj[key][Object.keys(obj[key])[0]] !== 'symbol') {
                getCurrentWeather(obj[key]);
            }else {
                weatherCon = obj[key];
            }
        } else if (key === weather.weather[0].description) {
            if (typeof obj[key][Object.keys(obj[key])[0]] !== 'symbol') {
                getCurrentWeather(obj[key]);
            }else {
                weatherCon = obj[key];
            }
        } else if (key === 'day') {
            if (weather?.weather[0].icon?.includes("d")) {
                weatherCon = obj[key];
            } else {
                continue
            }
        } else if (key === 'night') {
            if (weather?.weather[0].icon?.includes("d")) {
                continue
            } else {
                weatherCon = obj[key];
            }
        } else {
            continue
        }
    }
    return weatherCon;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).